# Ant / Android - Reduce Compile Time

Tags: android, ant

I work on a small Android application project that comprises of ~5k lines of code and a handful of resources.  It also has a few library dependencies in the lib/ folder.  The problem is that my compile time is very slow.  Suppose I perform the following:

```
ant clean debug
```

This takes about 28 seconds.  Performing a subsequent:

```
ant debug
```

Still takes 9 seconds even though I've made not changes to the source between compilation.

It seems like the majority of the slowness happens during the '-dex' target.

How can I improve the speed performance of my Android builds?

Please take a look at this link for my edited 'ant clean debug' output: http://pastebin.com/XY08mr5G

I'm using:
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4, Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31, Android SDK Tools 22.01, 
Android SDK Platform-tools 17, Android SDK Build-tools 17

Thanks.

Comment: My question has been downvoted.  What can I do to improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight, my core issue is that I don't trust Ant to correctly track which sources have been modified since last build.  I often find myself running 'ant clean debug' every time I compile simply because I've been burned too many times with botched builds.

If only I had a target to perform a fresh compile of my sources without actually redexing all of my dependency libraries each time!

Here's a proposed solution to my problem.  Add this Ant target to my project's build.xml:

```
<target name="cl">
    <delete file="bin/classes.dex" />
    <delete file="bin/classes.dex.d" />
    <delete dir="bin/classes" />
</target>
```

Now running 'ant cl debug' takes considerably less time, clocking in at 5 seconds.  All of my Java source files are recompiled, but the libraries are not re-dexed each time. (which the 'clean' target requires *every* time)

I'm content with this solution and will await Android's future [Gradle based build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).  With any luck, it will provide more versatile targets than this Ant based system.

Answer (score 0):

28 seconds that's not so much for an Ant build script. Compiling to a dex format does take a while. I don't know when you run the ant build script but while you are developing you better use an IDE with compiler such as Eclipse and it will compile in background. Use the Ant build script when you create a build for testing or releasing.